# Why can't search argument handle more than 1 character in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

More than 2 characters in s argument "breaks" search results and displays 404.

Search query WITHOUT results displays 404.

Plugins:
Polylang v3.3.2

Theme:
Custom theme

#### My goals:

http://website.local/animals/?s=E (template home.php)

animals page (template home.php) displaying a search result containing posts with letter "E" or "e" in title

http://website.local/animals/?s=Enzo (template home.php)

animals page (template home.php) displaying a search result containing a post with title "Enzo"

#### What's happening:

http://website.local/animals/?s=E (template home.php)

animals page (template home.php) displaying a search result containing posts with letter "E" or "e" in title

http://website.local/animals/?s=Enzo (template home.php)

**404 not found**

### **My theme files:**

#### *index.php*

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Standart page
*/
get_header();
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
else :
    echo '404';

endif;

get_footer();

?>
```

#### *home.php*

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Animals
*/
$category = array ();
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status’' => 'publish',
  's' => get_query_var( 's' )
);
$blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

get_header();

get_search_form();
if ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) :
        $blog_posts->the_post();
        echo '<h2>'.the_title().'</h2>';
    endwhile;
}
else echo '<div>No items</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();

get_footer(); ?>
```

#### *searchform.php*

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form">
        <input
            type="search"
            class="search-field"
            name="s"
            title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>"
            value="<?php echo get_search_query();?>"
        />
        <label class="submitl" for="submit">
            <input hidden type="submit" id="submit"/>
        </label>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### *functions.php*

```
<?php

function custom_theme_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_assets' );
```

Comment: Change the argument name in the URL from "s" to "search" or whatever. Make sure the argument name remains the same.(in $args = array(...))

Comment: There is really no apparent reason why the length of the parameter value should make any difference. Are you getting the `echo '404'` output from the index.php shown here, or are you getting an actual 404 error from WordPress itself?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @CBroe I was getting echo '404' output from index.php.
And a 404 HTTP response (from browser console)